# "Too many redirects" when securing micronaut app with openid (keycloak)

Tags: keycloak, micronaut

**Endpoints:**

- "/hello" (SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS) returns TEXT_PLAIN "hello world"
- "/admin" (SecurityRule.IS_AUTHENTICATED) returns TEXT_PLAIN "hello admin"

**application.yml:**

```
micronaut:
  security:
    enabled: true
    oauth2:
      enabled: true
      default-provider: keycloak
      callback-uri: /loggedin{/provider}
      login-uri: /{/provider}
      clients:
        keycloak:
          client-id: helloclient
          client-secret: SECRET
          openid:
            issuer: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/hellorealm
    token:
      jwt:
        enabled: true
        cookie:
          enabled: false
    session:
      enabled: true
```

**pom.xml:**

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.configuration</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-security-jwt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-security-session</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-security</artifactId>
```

**Behaviour:**

On "/hello" I see "hello world".

On "/admin" I'm redirected to Keycloak's login page, which is what I want. After successful login, "GET /" seems to be requested over and over and I see "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" eventually. Instead, I expected "hello admin" to appear.

**Question:**
What's wrong and how do I fix this?

I'm new to Micronaut, so an "idiot" explanation might be necessary.

**EDIT**

**Keycloak's conf and log**

The realm has one user(no roles) and one confidential client with only standard flow enabled.
The described use case does not trigger any output in the log. The user has an active session after login.
Version 7.0.1 is used.

**APP's log**

```
$ mvn compile exec:exec
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< hello.world:hello-world >-----------------------
[INFO] Building hello-world 0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ hello-world ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ hello-world ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (default-cli) @ hello-world ---
11:13:42.857 [main] DEBUG i.m.s.o.client.OpenIdClientFactory - Sending request for OpenID configuration for provider [keycloak] to URL [http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/hellorealm/.well-known/openid-configuration]
11:13:43.192 [main] DEBUG i.m.s.o.e.e.r.EndSessionEndpointResolver - Resolving the end session endpoint for provider [keycloak]. Looking for a bean with the provider name qualifier
11:13:43.196 [main] DEBUG i.m.s.o.e.e.r.EndSessionEndpointResolver - No EndSessionEndpoint bean found with a name qualifier of [keycloak]
11:13:43.199 [main] DEBUG i.m.s.o.e.e.r.EndSessionEndpointResolver - No EndSessionEndpoint can be resolved. The issuer for provider [keycloak] does not match any of the providers supported by default
11:13:43.221 [main] DEBUG i.m.s.o.routes.OauthRouteBuilder - Registering login route [GET: ] for oauth configuration [keycloak]
11:13:43.223 [main] DEBUG i.m.s.o.routes.OauthRouteBuilder - Registering default login route [GET: /] for oauth configuration [keycloak]
11:13:43.224 [main] DEBUG i.m.s.o.routes.OauthRouteBuilder - Registering callback route [GET: /loggedin/keycloak] for oauth configuration [keycloak]
11:13:43.224 [main] DEBUG i.m.s.o.routes.OauthRouteBuilder - Registering callback route [POST: /loggedin/keycloak] for oauth configuration [keycloak]
11:13:43.225 [main] DEBUG i.m.s.o.routes.OauthRouteBuilder - Registering default callback route [GET: /loggedin] for oauth configuration [keycloak]
11:13:43.225 [main] DEBUG i.m.s.o.routes.OauthRouteBuilder - Registering default callback route [POST: /loggedin] for oauth configuration [keycloak]
11:13:43.225 [main] DEBUG i.m.s.o.routes.OauthRouteBuilder - Skipped registration of logout route. No openid clients found that support end session
11:13:43.265 [main] INFO  io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Startup completed in 12074ms. Server Running: http://localhost:8086
11:13:48.212 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-18] DEBUG i.m.s.o.e.t.r.p.PasswordGrantFactory - Skipped password grant flow for provider [keycloak] because the grant type is not 'password'
11:13:48.248 [pool-1-thread-4] DEBUG i.m.s.t.reader.HttpHeaderTokenReader - Looking for bearer token in Authorization header
11:13:48.249 [pool-1-thread-4] DEBUG i.m.s.t.reader.HttpHeaderTokenReader - Looking for bearer token in Authorization header
11:13:48.249 [pool-1-thread-4] DEBUG i.m.s.t.reader.DefaultTokenResolver - Request GET, /hello, no token found.
11:13:48.251 [pool-1-thread-4] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - No Authentication fetched for request. GET /hello.
11:13:48.253 [pool-1-thread-4] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Authorized request GET /hello. The rule provider io.micronaut.security.rules.SecuredAnnotationRule authorized the request.
11:13:48.330 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-18] DEBUG i.m.s.t.reader.HttpHeaderTokenReader - Looking for bearer token in Authorization header
11:13:48.331 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-18] DEBUG i.m.s.t.reader.HttpHeaderTokenReader - Looking for bearer token in Authorization header
11:13:48.331 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-18] DEBUG i.m.s.t.reader.DefaultTokenResolver - Request GET, /favicon.ico, no token found.
11:13:48.331 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-18] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - No Authentication fetched for request. GET /favicon.ico.
11:13:48.333 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-18] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Authorized request GET /favicon.ico. No rule provider authorized or rejected the request.
11:13:56.693 [pool-1-thread-4] DEBUG i.m.s.t.reader.HttpHeaderTokenReader - Looking for bearer token in Authorization header
11:13:56.693 [pool-1-thread-4] DEBUG i.m.s.t.reader.HttpHeaderTokenReader - Looking for bearer token in Authorization header
11:13:56.693 [pool-1-thread-4] DEBUG i.m.s.t.reader.DefaultTokenResolver - Request GET, /admin, no token found.
11:13:56.693 [pool-1-thread-4] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - No Authentication fetched for request. GET /admin.
11:13:56.694 [pool-1-thread-4] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Unauthorized request GET /admin. The rule provider io.micronaut.security.rules.SecuredAnnotationRule rejected the request.
11:13:56.713 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-20] DEBUG i.m.s.t.reader.HttpHeaderTokenReader - Looking for bearer token in Authorization header
11:13:56.713 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-20] DEBUG i.m.s.t.reader.HttpHeaderTokenReader - Looking for bearer token in Authorization header
11:13:56.713 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-20] DEBUG i.m.s.t.reader.DefaultTokenResolver - Request GET, /, no token found.
11:13:56.714 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-20] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - No Authentication fetched for request. GET /.
11:13:56.714 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-20] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Authorized request GET /. The rule provider io.micronaut.security.rules.SecuredAnnotationRule authorized the request.
11:14:01.578 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-21] DEBUG i.m.s.t.reader.HttpHeaderTokenReader - Looking for bearer token in Authorization header
11:14:01.579 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-21] DEBUG i.m.s.t.reader.HttpHeaderTokenReader - Looking for bearer token in Authorization header
11:14:01.579 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-21] DEBUG i.m.s.t.reader.DefaultTokenResolver - Request GET, /loggedin/keycloak, no token found.
11:14:01.579 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-21] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - No Authentication fetched for request. GET /loggedin/keycloak.
11:14:01.580 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-21] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Authorized request GET /loggedin/keycloak. The rule provider io.micronaut.security.rules.SecuredAnnotationRule authorized the request.
11:14:01.662 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-22] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.s.jwks.JwksSignature - JWT validation URL: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/hellorealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
11:14:01.709 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-22] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.v.JwtTokenValidatorUtils - JWT is signed
11:14:01.710 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-22] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.v.JwtTokenValidatorUtils - Using signature configuration: io.micronaut.security.token.jwt.signature.jwks.JwksSignature@650a71aa
11:14:01.712 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-22] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.s.jwks.JwksSignature - Found 1 matching JWKs
11:14:01.732 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-22] DEBUG i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path /loggedin/keycloak, cookie value NjY3ODFjNWItYzMzYy00YTJiLWJmMTgtYjBiZWY0ZmViMmJh
11:14:01.749 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-23] DEBUG i.m.s.h.CookieHttpSessionIdGenerator - cookie value: NjY3ODFjNWItYzMzYy00YTJiLWJmMTgtYjBiZWY0ZmViMmJh
11:14:01.749 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-23] DEBUG i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path 66781c5b-c33c-4a2b-bf18-b0bef4feb2ba, session id: /
11:14:01.752 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-23] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Attributes: acr=>1, email_verified=>false, azp=>helloclient, auth_time=>1579256041, roles=>[], typ=>ID, preferred_username=>testuser, session_state=>97dc8d71-1e01-4cc4-b975-c5956bd56700, oauth2Provider=>keycloak, username=>0d348cc9-e8ef-41bd-9628-7d9ec58972d8
11:14:01.752 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-23] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Authorized request GET /. The rule provider io.micronaut.security.rules.SecuredAnnotationRule authorized the request.
11:14:01.754 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-23] DEBUG i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path /, cookie value NjY3ODFjNWItYzMzYy00YTJiLWJmMTgtYjBiZWY0ZmViMmJh
11:14:01.784 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-24] DEBUG i.m.s.h.CookieHttpSessionIdGenerator - cookie value: NjY3ODFjNWItYzMzYy00YTJiLWJmMTgtYjBiZWY0ZmViMmJh
11:14:01.784 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-24] DEBUG i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path 66781c5b-c33c-4a2b-bf18-b0bef4feb2ba, session id: /loggedin/keycloak
11:14:01.784 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-24] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Attributes: acr=>1, email_verified=>false, azp=>helloclient, auth_time=>1579256041, roles=>[], typ=>ID, preferred_username=>testuser, session_state=>97dc8d71-1e01-4cc4-b975-c5956bd56700, oauth2Provider=>keycloak, username=>0d348cc9-e8ef-41bd-9628-7d9ec58972d8
11:14:01.785 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-24] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Authorized request GET /loggedin/keycloak. The rule provider io.micronaut.security.rules.SecuredAnnotationRule authorized the request.
11:14:01.818 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-25] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.s.jwks.JwksSignature - JWT validation URL: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/hellorealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
11:14:01.824 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-25] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.v.JwtTokenValidatorUtils - JWT is signed
11:14:01.824 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-25] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.v.JwtTokenValidatorUtils - Using signature configuration: io.micronaut.security.token.jwt.signature.jwks.JwksSignature@190712ff
11:14:01.824 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-25] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.s.jwks.JwksSignature - Found 1 matching JWKs
11:14:01.829 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-25] DEBUG i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path /loggedin/keycloak, cookie value NjY3ODFjNWItYzMzYy00YTJiLWJmMTgtYjBiZWY0ZmViMmJh
11:14:01.845 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-26] DEBUG i.m.s.h.CookieHttpSessionIdGenerator - cookie value: NjY3ODFjNWItYzMzYy00YTJiLWJmMTgtYjBiZWY0ZmViMmJh
11:14:01.845 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-26] DEBUG i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path 66781c5b-c33c-4a2b-bf18-b0bef4feb2ba, session id: /
11:14:01.846 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-26] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Attributes: acr=>0, email_verified=>false, azp=>helloclient, auth_time=>1579256041, roles=>[], typ=>ID, preferred_username=>testuser, session_state=>97dc8d71-1e01-4cc4-b975-c5956bd56700, oauth2Provider=>keycloak, username=>0d348cc9-e8ef-41bd-9628-7d9ec58972d8
11:14:01.846 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-26] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Authorized request GET /. The rule provider io.micronaut.security.rules.SecuredAnnotationRule authorized the request.
11:14:01.850 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-26] DEBUG i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path /, cookie value NjY3ODFjNWItYzMzYy00YTJiLWJmMTgtYjBiZWY0ZmViMmJh
11:14:01.876 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-27] DEBUG i.m.s.h.CookieHttpSessionIdGenerator - cookie value: NjY3ODFjNWItYzMzYy00YTJiLWJmMTgtYjBiZWY0ZmViMmJh
11:14:01.877 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-27] DEBUG i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path 66781c5b-c33c-4a2b-bf18-b0bef4feb2ba, session id: /loggedin/keycloak
11:14:01.877 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-27] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Attributes: acr=>0, email_verified=>false, azp=>helloclient, auth_time=>1579256041, roles=>[], typ=>ID, preferred_username=>testuser, session_state=>97dc8d71-1e01-4cc4-b975-c5956bd56700, oauth2Provider=>keycloak, username=>0d348cc9-e8ef-41bd-9628-7d9ec58972d8
11:14:01.878 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-27] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Authorized request GET /loggedin/keycloak. The rule provider io.micronaut.security.rules.SecuredAnnotationRule authorized the request.
11:14:01.914 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-28] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.s.jwks.JwksSignature - JWT validation URL: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/hellorealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
11:14:01.921 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-28] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.v.JwtTokenValidatorUtils - JWT is signed
11:14:01.922 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-28] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.v.JwtTokenValidatorUtils - Using signature configuration: io.micronaut.security.token.jwt.signature.jwks.JwksSignature@62789236
11:14:01.922 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-28] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.s.jwks.JwksSignature - Found 1 matching JWKs
11:14:01.925 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-28] DEBUG i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path /loggedin/keycloak, cookie value NjY3ODFjNWItYzMzYy00YTJiLWJmMTgtYjBiZWY0ZmViMmJh
11:14:01.940 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-29] DEBUG i.m.s.h.CookieHttpSessionIdGenerator - cookie value: NjY3ODFjNWItYzMzYy00YTJiLWJmMTgtYjBiZWY0ZmViMmJh
11:14:01.940 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-29] DEBUG i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path 66781c5b-c33c-4a2b-bf18-b0bef4feb2ba, session id: /
11:14:01.941 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-29] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Attributes: acr=>0, email_verified=>false, azp=>helloclient, auth_time=>1579256041, roles=>[], typ=>ID, preferred_username=>testuser, session_state=>97dc8d71-1e01-4cc4-b975-c5956bd56700, oauth2Provider=>keycloak, username=>0d348cc9-e8ef-41bd-9628-7d9ec58972d8
11:14:01.942 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-29] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Authorized request GET /. The rule provider io.micronaut.security.rules.SecuredAnnotationRule authorized the request.
11:14:01.945 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-29] DEBUG i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path /, cookie value NjY3ODFjNWItYzMzYy00YTJiLWJmMTgtYjBiZWY0ZmViMmJh
11:14:01.974 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-30] DEBUG i.m.s.h.CookieHttpSessionIdGenerator - cookie value: NjY3ODFjNWItYzMzYy00YTJiLWJmMTgtYjBiZWY0ZmViMmJh
11:14:01.974 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-30] DEBUG i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path 66781c5b-c33c-4a2b-bf18-b0bef4feb2ba, session id: /loggedin/keycloak
11:14:01.974 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-30] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Attributes: acr=>0, email_verified=>false, azp=>helloclient, auth_time=>1579256041, roles=>[], typ=>ID, preferred_username=>testuser, session_state=>97dc8d71-1e01-4cc4-b975-c5956bd56700, oauth2Provider=>keycloak, username=>0d348cc9-e8ef-41bd-9628-7d9ec58972d8
11:14:01.974 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-30] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Authorized request GET /loggedin/keycloak. The rule provider io.micronaut.security.rules.SecuredAnnotationRule authorized the request.
11:14:02.008 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-31] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.s.jwks.JwksSignature - JWT validation URL: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/hellorealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
11:14:02.015 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-31] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.v.JwtTokenValidatorUtils - JWT is signed
11:14:02.015 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-31] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.v.JwtTokenValidatorUtils - Using signature configuration: io.micronaut.security.token.jwt.signature.jwks.JwksSignature@5b093c1f
11:14:02.015 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-31] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.s.jwks.JwksSignature - Found 1 matching JWKs
11:14:02.019 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-31] DEBUG i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path /loggedin/keycloak, cookie value NjY3ODFjNWItYzMzYy00YTJiLWJmMTgtYjBiZWY0ZmViMmJh
11:14:02.039 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-32] DEBUG i.m.s.h.CookieHttpSessionIdGenerator - cookie value: NjY3ODFjNWItYzMzYy00YTJiLWJmMTgtYjBiZWY0ZmViMmJh
11:14:02.039 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-32] DEBUG i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path 66781c5b-c33c-4a2b-bf18-b0bef4feb2ba, session id: /
11:14:02.041 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-32] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Attributes: acr=>0, email_verified=>false, azp=>helloclient, auth_time=>1579256041, roles=>[], typ=>ID, preferred_username=>testuser, session_state=>97dc8d71-1e01-4cc4-b975-c5956bd56700, oauth2Provider=>keycloak, username=>0d348cc9-e8ef-41bd-9628-7d9ec58972d8
11:14:02.041 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-32] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Authorized request GET /. The rule provider io.micronaut.security.rules.SecuredAnnotationRule authorized the request.
11:14:02.043 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-32] DEBUG i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path /, cookie value NjY3ODFjNWItYzMzYy00YTJiLWJmMTgtYjBiZWY0ZmViMmJh
11:14:02.067 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-33] DEBUG i.m.s.h.CookieHttpSessionIdGenerator - cookie value: NjY3ODFjNWItYzMzYy00YTJiLWJmMTgtYjBiZWY0ZmViMmJh
11:14:02.068 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-33] DEBUG i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path 66781c5b-c33c-4a2b-bf18-b0bef4feb2ba, session id: /loggedin/keycloak
11:14:02.069 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-33] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Attributes: acr=>0, email_verified=>false, azp=>helloclient, auth_time=>1579256041, roles=>[], typ=>ID, preferred_username=>testuser, session_state=>97dc8d71-1e01-4cc4-b975-c5956bd56700, oauth2Provider=>keycloak, username=>0d348cc9-e8ef-41bd-9628-7d9ec58972d8
11:14:02.070 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-33] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Authorized request GET /loggedin/keycloak. The rule provider io.micronaut.security.rules.SecuredAnnotationRule authorized the request.
11:14:02.101 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-34] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.s.jwks.JwksSignature - JWT validation URL: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/hellorealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
11:14:02.106 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-34] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.v.JwtTokenValidatorUtils - JWT is signed
11:14:02.107 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-34] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.v.JwtTokenValidatorUtils - Using signature configuration: io.micronaut.security.token.jwt.signature.jwks.JwksSignature@4bc35592
11:14:02.107 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-34] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.s.jwks.JwksSignature - Found 1 matching JWKs
11:14:02.111 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-34] DEBUG i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path /loggedin/keycloak, cookie value NjY3ODFjNWItYzMzYy00YTJiLWJmMTgtYjBiZWY0ZmViMmJh
11:14:02.124 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-35] DEBUG i.m.s.h.CookieHttpSessionIdGenerator - cookie value: NjY3ODFjNWItYzMzYy00YTJiLWJmMTgtYjBiZWY0ZmViMmJh
11:14:02.124 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-35] DEBUG i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path 66781c5b-c33c-4a2b-bf18-b0bef4feb2ba, session id: /
11:14:02.126 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-35] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Attributes: acr=>0, email_verified=>false, azp=>helloclient, auth_time=>1579256041, roles=>[], typ=>ID, preferred_username=>testuser, session_state=>97dc8d71-1e01-4cc4-b975-c5956bd56700, oauth2Provider=>keycloak, username=>0d348cc9-e8ef-41bd-9628-7d9ec58972d8
11:14:02.126 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-35] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Authorized request GET /. The rule provider io.micronaut.security.rules.SecuredAnnotationRule authorized the request.
11:14:02.129 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-35] DEBUG i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path /, cookie value NjY3ODFjNWItYzMzYy00YTJiLWJmMTgtYjBiZWY0ZmViMmJh
11:14:02.147 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-36] DEBUG i.m.s.h.CookieHttpSessionIdGenerator - cookie value: NjY3ODFjNWItYzMzYy00YTJiLWJmMTgtYjBiZWY0ZmViMmJh
11:14:02.147 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-36] DEBUG i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path 66781c5b-c33c-4a2b-bf18-b0bef4feb2ba, session id: /loggedin/keycloak
11:14:02.148 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-36] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Attributes: acr=>0, email_verified=>false, azp=>helloclient, auth_time=>1579256041, roles=>[], typ=>ID, preferred_username=>testuser, session_state=>97dc8d71-1e01-4cc4-b975-c5956bd56700, oauth2Provider=>keycloak, username=>0d348cc9-e8ef-41bd-9628-7d9ec58972d8
11:14:02.148 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-36] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Authorized request GET /loggedin/keycloak. The rule provider io.micronaut.security.rules.SecuredAnnotationRule authorized the request.
11:14:02.177 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-37] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.s.jwks.JwksSignature - JWT validation URL: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/hellorealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
11:14:02.183 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-37] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.v.JwtTokenValidatorUtils - JWT is signed
11:14:02.183 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-37] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.v.JwtTokenValidatorUtils - Using signature configuration: io.micronaut.security.token.jwt.signature.jwks.JwksSignature@453a590f
11:14:02.183 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-37] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.s.jwks.JwksSignature - Found 1 matching JWKs
11:14:02.186 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-37] DEBUG i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path /loggedin/keycloak, cookie value NjY3ODFjNWItYzMzYy00YTJiLWJmMTgtYjBiZWY0ZmViMmJh
11:14:02.194 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-38] DEBUG i.m.s.h.CookieHttpSessionIdGenerator - cookie value: NjY3ODFjNWItYzMzYy00YTJiLWJmMTgtYjBiZWY0ZmViMmJh
11:14:02.194 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-38] DEBUG i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path 66781c5b-c33c-4a2b-bf18-b0bef4feb2ba, session id: /
11:14:02.195 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-38] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Attributes: acr=>0, email_verified=>false, azp=>helloclient, auth_time=>1579256041, roles=>[], typ=>ID, preferred_username=>testuser, session_state=>97dc8d71-1e01-4cc4-b975-c5956bd56700, oauth2Provider=>keycloak, username=>0d348cc9-e8ef-41bd-9628-7d9ec58972d8
11:14:02.195 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-38] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Authorized request GET /. The rule provider io.micronaut.security.rules.SecuredAnnotationRule authorized the request.
11:14:02.198 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-38] DEBUG i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path /, cookie value NjY3ODFjNWItYzMzYy00YTJiLWJmMTgtYjBiZWY0ZmViMmJh
11:14:02.217 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-39] DEBUG i.m.s.h.CookieHttpSessionIdGenerator - cookie value: NjY3ODFjNWItYzMzYy00YTJiLWJmMTgtYjBiZWY0ZmViMmJh
11:14:02.217 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-39] DEBUG i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path 66781c5b-c33c-4a2b-bf18-b0bef4feb2ba, session id: /loggedin/keycloak
11:14:02.218 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-39] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Attributes: acr=>0, email_verified=>false, azp=>helloclient, auth_time=>1579256041, roles=>[], typ=>ID, preferred_username=>testuser, session_state=>97dc8d71-1e01-4cc4-b975-c5956bd56700, oauth2Provider=>keycloak, username=>0d348cc9-e8ef-41bd-9628-7d9ec58972d8
11:14:02.218 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-39] DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Authorized request GET /loggedin/keycloak. The rule provider io.micronaut.security.rules.SecuredAnnotationRule authorized the request.
11:14:02.253 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-40] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.s.jwks.JwksSignature - JWT validation URL: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/hellorealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
11:14:02.258 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-40] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.v.JwtTokenValidatorUtils - JWT is signed
11:14:02.258 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-40] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.v.JwtTokenValidatorUtils - Using signature configuration: io.micronaut.security.token.jwt.signature.jwks.JwksSignature@220355fc
11:14:02.259 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-40] DEBUG i.m.s.t.j.s.jwks.JwksSignature - Found 1 matching JWKs
11:14:02.263 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-40] DEBUG i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path /loggedin/keycloak, cookie value NjY3ODFjNWItYzMzYy00YTJiLWJmMTgtYjBiZWY0ZmViMmJh
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your configuration.

You have set up the default login route to be `/`, therefore after the redirect back to `/`, it's redirecting back to keycloak.

Try:
`login-uri: /login{/provider}`

`/loggedin/keycloak` is triggering a redirect to `/`, which is triggering a redirect to keycloak which then transfers back to `/loggedin/keycloak`, thus the circle.

```
i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path /loggedin/keycloak, 
...
i.m.s.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy - path /,
```

Comment: The thing is, I don't want an explicit ```/login/``` uri, but the Keycloak login to be triggered from any endpoint in the API, if the user is not logged in yet. I played around with the config and `/` login route seems to give this functionality. Is there any other way to do it? because it does not seem to be the default behavior.  


So, the question now becomes,   



1) why does an explicitly set callback uri `loggedin/keycloak` redirect to `/` ?   <br/>
2) should not the framework stop redirecting to the auth provider on `/` (or any login route) once the user is logged in?

Comment: "not the framework stop redirecting to the auth provider on / (or any login route) once the user is logged in?" No because you configured it to do so